# Strange error message in Node.js

Tags: node.js, crash, express

I've been getting a lot of strange error message lately, and now I can't even get app.js started. What could the following mean, and does anyone know how to solve it?

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'port' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/henrikpetersson81/node/last/test4/app.js:15:64)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Comment: Probably a syntax error but we can't help unless you post the code.

Comment: It's a runtime error, not a syntax error. A syntax error would say "SyntaxError".

Comment: Can you show your code?

if you're using Express, be aware that express 3.0 has changed the way it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saw a [similar question recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068714/how-to-get-node-js-express-to-listen-only-on-localhost). You could be experiencing a similar issue. Perhaps one of the libraries you are using (or your own code) is trying to access `app.address().port` before the `app.listen` has completed and the corresponding callback has been invoked.

Answer (score 4):

The port is propably already used. It was with me the case.

Answer (score 1):

I found an article explaining the same error message, and it's a problem with the port. I changed the port from 3000 to 5959 and now it works. Strange though that the port suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Do you have another application, perhaps a ruby on rails app, already listening on port 3000?

Comment: Actually no, so it's kinda strange.

Comment: The same is with me! Port 3000 is not busy by other apps but NodeJS can't listen for it. REALLY strange!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It turns out while using nodemon( or simple for that matter) when u kill the node server it might not have been killed, so a server is still listening to 3000 port. To overcome this simple close the terminal and restart the server.(On ubuntu machine , using node and Nodemon)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where port:3000 is solely used by node.js script.
Killing the PID worked for me for port:3000.

```
lsof -i :3000
kill -9 <PID>
```

Answer (score 0):

the port that your localhost is listening to, is being used by some other application/service. try changing the port at the following location to a different port number like 8888 or 3000 and you should be good to go.

/Users/henrikpetersson81/node/last/test4/app.js