# How do i restrict my node express application to localhost only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a node express application that I want to only be available to the localhost client.
How can I prevent other hosts from accessing my node express app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Node.JS Express to listen only on localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068714/how-to-get-node-js-express-to-listen-only-on-localhost)

Comment: seems to be a different problem and solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you start listening your server just mentioned the host name as 'localhost'. Take a look at the following code.

```
var app = require('express')();
app.listen(8000,'localhost');
```

Comment: It should be:  app.listen(8000,'localhost');